# Multiple columns into single cell with comma separated values in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, lookup, msbi

I have a report where i need to show the data from multiple columns into single with comma separated based on the condition.

For Ex : Join(Lookupset((a=1,a=1,a,"DataSet1"),",") is the kind of expression that i want to use out side table or in the table shouldn't matter unless i get the all the column values from query in a text box based on the condition.

Now when i tried to use the above query the conditions in the look up set are not being considered by default all risks are showing up.

The expression:

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!Inherent_Likelihood.Value = 2 AND Fields!Inherent_Consequence.Value = 3 , 
    Fields!Inherent_Likelihood.Value = 2 AND Fields!Inherent_Consequence.Value = 3 , 
    Fields!Risk_ID.Value , "InherentHeatMapDataSet01"), ",")
```

Any Help would be much appreciated,Thanks in advance.

Regards,
VR

Comment: We are going to need to see the actual expression you are using. The example expression above has no value in this context.

Comment: **=Join(LookupSet(Fields!Inherent_Likelihood.Value = 2 AND Fields!Inherent_Consequence.Value = 3
    , Fields!Inherent_Likelihood.Value = 2 AND Fields!Inherent_Consequence.Value = 3
    , Fields!Risk_ID.Value
    , "InherentHeatMapDataSet01"), ",")**

In the above i want to show all risks id's as comma separated which satisfy the source and destination expression from the same data set.